# PHP fopen() creating file without permissions to modify it

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions

Executing the following from a PHP script called by apache:

```
$h = fopen(getcwd()."tmp.txt","w");
fprintf($h,"hi");
fclose($h);
```

generates a file owned by my personal userid with 644 permissions. However, executing the script again results in an error, since  Apache/PHP is running as user wwwrun and so doesn't have the permissions to overwrite the file or to chmod it.

The directory that the files are being placed is in my home directory and has 777 permissions. How can I get PHP to either create the file as owned by wwwrun, or create it with 666 permissions, or do something else, to allow it to be overwritten by PHP.

I am ideally looking for a solution which also applies to the situation where the file is created by PHP via an external program called with the `exec` function; this seems to suffer from the same problem, in that the external program runs as wwwrun, but files created by the external program are owned by my personal userid.

Comment: apache, running as www-data, could not possibly create a file with someone OTHER account's ownership. allowing non-root programs to change ownership to other users would be a massive security hole. is your home dir sgid/suid (2777/4777)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the directory in question was mounted on a file system that doesn't support linux file permissions.